# How to add floating particles to a fluid simulation?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I am trying to make a simple fluid simulation in Blender with floating particles in the fluid. I was able to create the fluid simulation, with materials and shadings to works. But I am having problems on how to add floating particles that follow the path of fluid.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this question myself and have not found an easy way to do it. I'm sure my answer isn't the best, but I hope it helps :D

Here we go:

1. Bake your fluid simulation
2. Create a plane and subdivide it a few times.
3. Shrinkwrap the object to your fluid simulation using the 'project' option.
   [image]
4. Then use object constraints to bind the 'floating' object to the plane you just created on the z-axis. Remember to create a vertex group on the plane and assign it to the constraint.
5. Constrain the plane to the floating object on the x-axis and y-axis
6. Tweak the offset to get the correct depth

[image]

Best of luck with your project and I hope I helped,

BFB

Comment: Oh, and you can hide the plane by disabling camera under cycles settings at the bottom in the object properties panel :D

Comment: In fact try to use this branch: https://graphicall.org/1240 ... its MantaFlow which **computes particles as a part of fluid** so You dont need to add anything, everything is "all inclusive" so to say ;). If some problems appear let me know here and I will write an Answer to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely try MantaFlow.

Comment: Tried a simple fluid example (a box as domain and a UV sphere as inflow) but MantaFlow did not work properly. I saw some comments on the website that you sent that had the same issue. Any thought on how to fix MantaFlow?